# How does a for .. Yield strip out a Future?

Tags: scala

I am struggling to understand how this code 'strips out' the Future.

`getFutureResult()` returns a `Future[String]`. So how come the return from the yield is only a `String`?

```
def getFutureResult:Future[String] = { ... }

def getMyResult:String = {

   for {
     myFutureResult <- getFutureResult()
   } yield {
     myFutureResult
   }

}
```

Comment: Because a `Future` behaves like a singleton `Set` - you are looping over the `String` that is contained in the `Future` and yielding that. The type of `myFutureResult` is `String`.

Comment: ok, but how do I know the future has completed?

Comment: none of this is going to compile... def getFutureResult: Future[String] isn't a function... you can't type getFutureResult()... also getMyResult doesn't strip out the String and won't compile either it's return type given the syntax you're using should be Future[String].

Answer (score 1):

It is translated according to Scala `for`-comprehension translation rules:

```
for (x <- <expr>) yield f(x)
```

becomes:

```
<expr>.map(x => f(x))
```

This is a desugaring done by the compiler irregardless if `<expr>` has the type of a collection, a future or something else.
`Future` in Scala has a method `map`, so it uses the `myFutureResult` `String` from above to construct another `Future[String]`.

You never know if the resulting future `getMyResult` is completed -- you should install an `onComplete` callback that will be called by the resulting future once it completes:

```
getMyResult onComplete {
  case Success(x) => println("Yes! " + x)
  case Failure(t) => println("An error: " + t)
}
```

The code for the `onComplete` method is executed asynchronously -- it might happen on a different thread, much later or simultaneously.

If you really need to know if the `Future` has completed, use the:

```
Await(getMyResult, 0 nanos)
```

pattern to block the calling thread until the `getMyResult` future is completed. In general, you should avoid this and compose your `Future` code using `for`-comprehensions and callback.

Comment: I see, so is a Future the same thing as an Async? Does using a Future mean non-blocking by default?

Comment: By default, all methods on `Future` are non-blocking, except the methods from the `Await` object.

Comment: @saintlyRook you should probably read more about Futures in general: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: @AndrewCassidy - thanks for the link. I was looking for a good documentation on futures.